# How to play a song using MusicKit SDK for Android

Tags: java, android, sdk, apple-music, apple-musickit

I'm trying to play a song using MusicKit SDK for Android, but I can't figure out how to play a certain song by its ID.
For instance I have this apple music song Id: "1440783625" (Smells Like Teen Spirit by Nirvana) and I want to play this song using MusicKit SDK, and I already managed to authenticate with my Apple Music premium account and play the example songs in their [example app](https://developer.apple.com/musickit/), but I can't understand their unreadable code (obviously intentional) and they don't have a real documentation / guide for android, they only have a javadoc with not much explenations on how to do stuff, and only what stuff do...

I'd love to get some help from someone who managed to use MusicKit :)

Answer (score 1):

I am working on an open source Apple music alternative right now actually and I have implemented library functionality so far. It requires setting up various media callbacks and passing them to MusicKit as well as a foreground service. Working code can be found here https://github.com/bmc08gt/upgraded-guacamole